# Como manipular Labels usando um loop

Tags: java, swing, loop

Como posso fazer para utilizar estes labels usando um loop, em vez de criar 40 linhas de código repetidas?

```
jLabel1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/cards/"+cards.get(1)+".png")));
jLabel2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/cards/"+cards.get(1)+".png")));
jLabel3.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/cards/"+cards.get(2)+".png")));
jLabel4.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/cards/"+cards.get(3)+".png")));
```

Comment: porque em inglês? (engano?)

Comment: @Earendul A pergunta estava em inglês e eu traduzi, só me esqueci de comentar aqui, desculpe. Talvez a dificuldade dele esteja em pegar o objeto `jLabel + i`, mas como eu não conheço java não posso opinar sobre isso...

Comment: Acho que foi um CTRL+C, CTRL+V meio apressado. Vejam: [Loop using jLabels in swing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25806201/1964435).

Comment: não, primeiro coloquei aqui, depois é que vi que estava na seccão de português. o control+C foi daqui para o outro.
Primeiro dia, primeiro post....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rodrigo,

você pode criar um vetor de jLabel:

```
JLabel [ ] labels = new JLabel [40];
for (int i=0; i < labels.length; i++){
   labels[i] = new JLabel ( );
   //Todo o codigo que voce precisar que aqui.
}
```

Comment: eu não queria era criar novos Labels, como estou a usar swing, criei o layout já com os 40 labels

Comment: Rodrigo, acredito que talvez seja mais fácil você modificar a forma de declaração dos seus 40 labels. Para poder modificar os seus atributos sem precisar replicar as 40 linhas. Do mesmo modo que você replicou na declaração. Ou então, atribuir o seus labels já declarados a uma posição do vetor. Tipo `labels[0] = jLabel1; labels[1] = jLabel2;`

Comment: @RodrigoCipriano na verdade você criou um vetor de variáveis de referências de Labels, os objetos JLabel's não estarão criados ao fim da linha `JLabel [] labels = new JLabel [40];`. Se você não der um `new` para cada uma dessas variáveis de referências você irá se deparar com um `NullPointerException` quando tentar acessá-las. Ou seja, essa resposta está certa.